# Tomcat 9 failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm trying to run Tomcat 9 on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ (running Raspbian) and I get this error when trying to start up:

```
30-Jan-2019 17:27:53.934 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
```

Note: Raspbian is a Debian OS.

Comment: Please post the complete trace, have you enabled SSL?

Comment: Full trace: https://pastebin.com/5F7eCx9S

Answer (score 1):

As the logs say:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:236)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1085)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1098)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:557)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:976)
    ... 13 more
```

also:

```
Failed to create server shutdown socket on address [localhost] and port [8005] (base port [8005] and offset [0])
```

which means some of the ports are occupied by another process (8080, 8005, 8009)

You can test it by:

```
telnet localhost 8080
```

You can know which process occupies which port by:

```
netstat -tulpn
```

Comment: Connection refused after using telnet.

Comment: Please also check for ports 8005 and 8009 (as seen from the logs)

Comment: Connection refused on both, and according to netstat nothing in the 8000s is being used,

Comment: Ports are network-card specific, I hope you have only one network interface.

Comment: I'm using a Raspberry Pi, so I assume I would only have one.

Comment: I have to say, the port is occupied, please look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737293/how-do-i-resolve-the-java-net-bindexception-address-already-in-use-jvm-bind, another option is to change the ports in `server.xml` to something else